# Run Applescript over all tabs in window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, applescript

I would like to run the following AppleScript on all tabs in a google chrome.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1

    execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('bt bt3 bw4')[0].click();"

end tell
```

I have managed to run it on all tabs within Safari using;

```
tell application "Safari"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows

        do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('bt bt3 bw4')[0].click();" in t
    end repeat

end tell
```

But can't replicate this in Chrome.

Anyone have any advice or know if this is achievable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As you've not provided a **URL** to test against `getElementsByClassName('bt bt3 bw4')`, I have opened several **Google Chrome** *windows* each with several *tabs* with the **URL** of this question and targeted the **Ask Question** *button*, which has a *class name* of `ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary`.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* worked for me in that it click every **Ask Question** *button* on every *tab* of every **Google Chrome** *window*:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    repeat with t in tabs of windows
        tell t to execute javascript "document.getElementsByClassName('ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary')[0].click();"
    end repeat
end tell
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal scroll to see full *code*.</sup>

Replacing the *class name* `ws-nowrap s-btn s-btn__primary`, in the *example* **AppleScript** *code* above, with `bt bt3 bw4` should work for you in this **Google Chrome** *version* of the *code* if it worked in the **Safari** *version* of the *code*.

---

**Notes:**

<sub>• If there is more then one *object* with the same *class name* of `'bt bt3 bw4` then the `getElementsByClassName()` HTML DOM Method will need to have the proper *index value* if it's not `[0]`. This can require additional coding to programmatically determine the proper *value* if it's not a constant *value* that you supply.</sub>

<sub>• The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>